# javascript to change classes of switch buttons and elements

Tags: javascript, css

Hi,

a friend gave me this code that changes the class of the switch buttons but I made a modification so each button change the state of 2 separate elements by pressing them like this

```
function toggleClass(ev){
  var el = document.querySelector(".pressed");
  var fro = document.querySelector(".visible"); <--line added
  el.className = 'notpressed';
  ev.target.className = 'pressed';

  fro.className = 'notvisible'; <--line added
  ev.target.className = 'visible'; <--line added
}

span{
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #FCFCFC;
}
.notpressed{
  background:#CCC;
}
.pressed{
  background: #DFF789;
}
.visible{
  display:block;
}
.notvisible{
  display: none;
}

<span id="but1" class="pressed" onclick="toggleClass(event);">BUTTON 1</span>
<span id="but2" class="notpressed" onclick="toggleClass(event);">BUTTON 2</span>

<div id="elem1">hello<div>
<div id="elem2">bye<div>
```

but its not working. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close some of your `div`. Try the following way:

```js
//initial setting
document.getElementById('elem2').className = 'notvisible';
document.getElementById('elem1').className = 'visible';
//on change
function toggleClass(ev){
  var fro = document.querySelector(".visible");
  var fro2 = document.querySelector(".notvisible");
  if(ev.target.id == 'but1'){
 document.getElementById('elem2').className = 'notvisible';
 document.getElementById('elem1').className = 'visible';
 ev.target.className = 'pressed';
 document.getElementById('but2').className = 'notpressed';
  }
  else if(ev.target.id == 'but2'){
 document.getElementById('elem1').className = 'notvisible'; 
 document.getElementById('elem2').className = 'visible';
 ev.target.className = 'pressed';
 document.getElementById('but1').className = 'notpressed';
  }
}
```

```css
span{
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #FCFCFC;
}
.notpressed{
  background:#CCC;
}
.pressed{
  background: #DFF789;
}
.visible{
  display:block;
}
.notvisible{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span id="but1" class="pressed" onclick="toggleClass(event);">BUTTON 1</span>
<span id="but2" class="notpressed" onclick="toggleClass(event);">BUTTON 2</span>



<div id="elem1" class="visible">hello</div>
<div id="elem2" class="notvisible">bye</div>
```

Comment: Thank you although the name of the class for the elements is visible and notvisible respectively but I guess I only need to change btn1 and btn2 to those, right?

Comment: @CainNuke, yes, you are right. I have updated my answer...thanks.

Comment: @CainNuke, sorry to mention that you need to reset `pressed & notpressed` classes as required. Please see the updated snippet...thanks

Comment: Thank you again. Another question. The initial setting goes OUTSIDE the function?

Comment: @CainNuke, yes, because if one of your button indicates that it is clicked or selected initially, then you need to place the setting outside the function...Thanks.

Comment: Great. One more question please. I tried it on firefox and it works fine but not on chrome and it says toggleClass is not defined. Have any idea why?

Comment: @CainNuke, I did the checking in  `Google Chrome - Version 62.0.3202.94` and it was working as expected...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your toggle class function you set the class 'visible' on the clicked button.  I assume you want to set the class on `#elem1` or `#elem2`.

You'll also need a way to associate the button element with the div that you want to hide or show.